# how to get full path of uploaded file in php?

Tags: php, html

My code snippet so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {
    $uploaddir = '/www/csvExtraction/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    }
```

Still i get this error

> Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\csvExtraction\index.php

---

Whole Code :

```
if(!$db)

die("no db");

if(!mysqli_select_db($db,"phptester"))

die("No database selected.");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$uploaddir = '/www/csvExtraction/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
{

$handle = fopen("$uploadfile", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
$import="INSERT into sample(id,name,address) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
mysqli_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
fclose($handle);
print "Import done";
}
}
else

{

print "<form action='index.php' method='post'>";

print "Choose file to import:<br><br>";

print "<input type='file' name='file' id='file'><br><br>";

//print "<input type='text' name='filename' size='20'><br>";

print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='extract'></form>";

}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("could not connect");

if(!$db)

die("no db");

if(!mysqli_select_db($db,"phptester"))

die("No database selected.");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo $uploadfile;


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) 
{

$handle = fopen("$uploadfile", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
$import="INSERT into sample(id,name,address) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
mysqli_query($db,$import) or die(mysql_error());
}
fclose($handle);
print "Import done";
}
}
else
{
print "<form action='index.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
print "Choose file to import:<br><br>";
print "<input type='file' name='file' id='file'><br><br>";
print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='extract'></form>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check `$_FILES['file']['name'] != ''`

before

`$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);`

and then retrieve it

Also, check `print_r($_FILES)` and see if you get anything there ?;

Answer (score 1):

check in your form is it `enctype="multipart/form-data"` contains this attr or not

Comment: now get this Warning: move_uploaded_file(/www/csvExtraction/uploads/Book2.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\csvExtraction\index.php

Comment: and this too : Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php4A25.tmp' to '/www/csvExtraction/uploads/Book2.csv' in C:\wamp\www\csvExtraction\index.php

Comment: could you please ensure that your code means .php page exists in which folder where you want to upload the file or not if yes then please change yout upload file directory path directly with this "uploads/" not make in front of this like www/etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the below things is proper in your html code.

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

Comment: yes, it is same as u write above.. still geting an error

Comment: see i have uploaded it here as an answer

Comment: put var_dump($_FILES); and see the result.